# Log-linear model in Jags

Tags: bayesian, jags

I'm trying to fit a log-linear model in JAGS. I'm using log for the y because negative values are impossible. I'm using a t-distribution to allow the heavy tails for the noise. The prior on the slope also does not allow positive values because the process is about degradation over time. For reference the best fit line using standard regression is: y = 70 – 0.20*x

The code:

```
  data {
    Ntotal <- length(y)
    for ( i in 1:length(y) ) {
      logy[i] <- log(y[i])
    }
  }
  # Specify the model for the data:
  model {
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      logy[i] ~ dt( Beta0 + Beta1 * x[i] , 1/Sigma^2 , nu )
    }
    # Priors vague on standardized scale:
      Beta0 ~ dunif( 0 , 5 )  
      Beta1 ~ dunif( -2 , 0 )
      Sigma ~ dunif( 0.01 , 5 )
      nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)
    # Transform to original scale:
      beta0 <- exp(Beta0)
      beta1 <- Beta1
      sigma <- exp(Sigma)
  }
```

When I check the posterior predictions against the data, the intercepts look reasonable, but the slopes are way too flat. It may be that I’m converting the slopes incorrectly.

Here's the output graph:

[image]

Ideally I would think the t-distribution for the noise would also squish up against the zero barrier as the x values increase. I’m not sure how to put that into the jags model though.

All tips are greatly appreciated,

Sean

Comment: Can you show your code for generating the posterior predictions?  And ideally, could you also post your data?  This will let us diagnose where the problem is.

Comment: @JacobSocolar,

Here's the data:

ID    x    y     
==========    
1    48    41.3    
2    144    43.1    
3    24    42.6    
4    48    105.0    
5    48    44.2    
6    48    86.3    
7    72    85.0    
8    96    68.0    
9    48    71.3    
10    48    38.3    
11    48    78.7    
12    120    44.1    
13    120    87.1    
14    120    40.8    
15    48    50.8    
16    96    25.8    
17    48    47.9    
18    120    13.7    
19    24    102.0    
20    24    36.5    
21    144    6.6    
22    168    64.1

Comment: After further reflection, I think the key is the transformation back into the raw scale. The intercept posterior is correct because exp(log of y-intercept) translates nicely into the raw y-intercept. The problem is that the log-linear slope is not translating back to the raw scale correctly. That’s why the slopes are so flat. They are showing samples of the posterior on the log scale, which has a median of -0.002052.

My log math is rusty so I haven’t been able to translate the log-linear slope back into the raw scale. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In parallel, I’m digging into the plotting code to see if there’s another way to display the posteriors with noise histograms on the raw scale.  The posteriors are displayed using the plotMCMC function from Doing Bayesian Analysis by Kruschke.

Comment: @JacobSocolar,  
    
    You 're right.  
  
    The plotting code is a key element. I changed the regression line plot command from linear to exponential:  

    # linear plot lines  
        lines( xComb , beta0[i]*exp(beta1[i]*xComb) , col="skyblue" )  
    # exponential plot lines  
        lines( xComb , beta0[i]*exp(beta1[i]*xComb) , col="skyblue" )